# Scala macro get enclosing line

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have the following  macro

```
object Example {
  def doIt(s: String): String = macro doItImpl

  def doItImpl(c: Context)(s: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.{ universe => u }
    import u._
    ???
  }
}
```

Instead of the `???` I would like to inspect the line where the method `doIt` was called to check if the result of the method was used (in an assignment, method call or whatever). If the result is not used I respond with an error-message.

Call-example:

```
val s: String = doIt("Hallo") // alright
doIt("Hallo") // ERROR!
```

Is there a simple way to get the Tree of the whole line?

Comment: See [this somewhat similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18450203/334519), the comments there, and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18451114/334519) for some ideas.

Comment: @TravisBrown I'm going to stay up late this Christmas Eve to try and catch Travis bringing macro answers to all the good girls and boys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness, here's a lightly adapted version of [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18451114/334519) I mention above:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object Example {
  def doIt(s: String): String = macro doItImpl

  def doItImpl(c: Context)(s: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._

    c.enclosingClass.collect {
      case ValDef(_, name, _, rhs) if rhs.pos == c.macroApplication.pos =>
        c.literal(s"Okay, defining a variable named ${name.decoded}.")
    }.headOption.getOrElse(
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not a valid application.")
    )
  }
}
```

Now in a REPL:

```
scala> import Example._
import Example._

scala> object Test1 { val x = doIt("foo") }
defined module Test1

scala> Test1.x
res0: String = Okay, defining a variable named x.
```

And in the case that we don't have an definition:

```
scala> object Test2 { doIt("foo") }
<console>:13: error: Not a valid application.
       object Test2 { doIt("foo") }
                          ^
```

As expected. See the comments on the question linked above for some caveats, but unless your real use case is much more complicated, this approach should work fine.

Comment: That addresses a part of the problem. I was aiming for something like the warning you get when typing `1 + 2` (a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary 
 parentheses). This is very difficult to achieve with extractors like `ValDef`. I guess there isn't another way?