# Scala macro for assigned value label in apply method

Tags: scala, scala-macros

From object `Naming` below (adapted from answer in [Scala macro get enclosing line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20466584/3189923)), which gathers the label associated to a value,

```
val x = Naming.apply("")
x: String = x
```

would like to modify the `apply` method so that it would deliver a new `Naming` instance where `assignedName` takes the assigned value label, namely,

```
val x = Naming()
assert( x.assignedName == "x")
```

In the code that follows, a *naîve* change like this

```
def apply(s: String): String = Naming( macro impl )
```

cannot work. Any working approach to instantiate `assignedName` is much valued.

```
case class Naming(var assignedName: String = "") {
  val m = collection.mutable.Map[String,Int]()
}

object Naming {

  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context

  def apply(s: String): String = macro impl 

  def impl(c: Context)(s: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[String] = {
    import c.universe._

    c.enclosingClass.collect {
      case ValDef(_, name, _, rhs) if rhs.pos == c.macroApplication.pos =>
        c.literal(name.decoded)
    }.headOption.getOrElse(
      c.literal("")
    )
  }

}
```

**Update** In `apply` method, `reify`'ing the `Naming` instance with `assisgnedName` updated might be a solution. If viable, how could this be implemented ?