# Is there an alternative to the deprecated enclosingClass method in Scala refelection library?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I am writing a macro to get the enclosing `val/var` definition. I can get the enclosing `val/var` symbol, but I can not get the defining tree. One solution here suggested using `enclosingClass`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18451114/11989864
But all the enclosing-tree style API is deprecated:
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/macros/blackbox/Context.html
Is there a way to implement the functionality of `enclosingClass`? Or to get a tree from a symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Reasons for deprecation are

> Starting from Scala 2.11.0, the APIs to get the trees enclosing by
>   the current macro application are deprecated, and the reasons for that
>   are two-fold. Firstly, we would like to move towards the philosophy of
>   locally-expanded macros, as it has proven to be important for
>   understanding of code. Secondly, within the current architecture of
>   scalac, we are unable to have `c.enclosingTree`-style APIs working
>   robustly. Required changes to the typechecker would greatly exceed the
>   effort that we would like to expend on this feature given the
>   existence of more pressing concerns at the moment. This is somewhat
>   aligned with the overall evolution of macros during the 2.11
>   development cycle, where we played with `c.introduceTopLevel` and
>   `c.introduceMember`, but at the end of the day decided to reject them.
>
> If you're relying on the now deprecated APIs, consider using the new
>   `c.internal.enclosingOwner` method that can be used to obtain the names
>   of enclosing definitions. Alternatively try reformulating your macros
>   in terms of completely local expansion...

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/macros/Enclosures.html

Regarding getting a tree from a symbol

> there's no standard way to go from a symbol to a defining tree

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13768595/5249621

Why do you need def macro to get the enclosing `val`/`var` definition?

Maybe macro annotatations can be enough 
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html

Comment: Thanks Dmytro.
I have multiple methods that are macro-expanded and can be chained or nested and I want to attach the name of the declared value to the final object. I can use run-time reflection to do that, but it only works in the class constructor scope, i.e. if I have nested scopes, I can not reflect on the declared values inside these scopes.

Comment: @MuhammadSoliman You can try macro annotations, compiler plugin or rewriting sources with Scalameta/Scalafix. Although `c.enclosingClass` is depecated it still seems to work (at least in some cases), you can try to continue using it so far (anyway current macros will be deprecated in Scala 3).

Comment: I wanted to avoid explicit annotations. I will probably use the `enclosingClass` for now. Thanks.